# Windows Explorer Won't Launch (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, troubleshooting

So this is my first post, because despite spending 4 hours attempting troubleshooting my issue last night nothing appeared to work.

I'm using a 4 year old Dell Inspiron 620, so it's not the best PC, and with what's been happening I have a bad feeling it might be my hardware, but just in case I was wondering if anyone could help me!

So yesterday I noticed that whenever I click on File Explorer or attempt to open it from anywhere (even through command prompt) it just doesn't open. The loading symbol comes up, my screen flashes, the task bar disappears for a second then nothing. The files are definitely still on my hard drive, as I can attach them to emails (and this is the only way I can see my files at all!) but no matter what I try, windows explorer will not open for me.

I have now done 2 repair installs without removing my data, so all my apps etc have been removed, yet the problem keeps going! Whenever I try sfc /scannow it gets to 49% of the verification phase then won't complete. I have attempted to run DISM /Online /Cleanup-image /RestoreHealth but it gives me an error message "Error 605 The specific buffer contains ill-formed data" but I can't even look at the log file because I can't get to it to try and figure out what's wrong!

This is becoming so frustrating as I really wan't to be able to access my files, even if it's just to back the essential ones up because I have a lot of important documents saved, and no, I haven't backed them up which I know is stupid but hindsight is 20-20 right?

Would really appreciate it if someone could help, and yes, I've tried adjusting screen size as mentioned in forums but mine is set to 100% as default so that's not it.

I'm currently running Windows 10 64 bit, I upgraded from Windows 7. I don't know if this is relevant at all, but I have recently been getting an error message at start up about 'System Fan Failure' but this has been going longer than the problem with explorer!

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Your system files appear to be corrupt, likely caused by hardware failure, which has nothing to do with the upgrade.  The fact you have repaired the installation multiple times indicates that.  Your just moving system files around. When you say you repair the installation your talking about you using the Reset option built into Windows 10 and selecting to choose to keep your personal files, right?

Comment: Yeah the reset option where I keep my personal files! Done that twice and after the first time I did have a horrible feeling it was my hardware, my system wasn't the best spec when I got it and has recently been struggling... Is there any way to save my essential data before my PC dies on me?